# Navigation component with bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I am working with navigation component and bottom navigation

```
val navController = indNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
bottom_navigation.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_navigation_menu)
bottom_navigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

and I am facing the next issue:

When an item is selected in the bottom navigation, then a fragment is loaded. The problem comes when I press again the same item, then a new fragment will be loaded, which it does not make sense at all.

Example:
1- User selects menu item A, then FragmentA is loaded.
2- User selects again menu item A, then a new FragmentA will be loaded,

I was trying to use

```
bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {  }
```

But then the bottom navigation will not work with the navController.

So the question is: there is a way to handle this situation in order to load again a new fragment when the user is in that screen already?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, I was able to fix this issue.

As I said before, this code:

```
bottom_navigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

is using

```
bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {  }
```

so every time I select / reselect an item, the navController will load a new fragment. I checked the javadoc for `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener()` and it says:

> Set a listener that will be notified when a bottom navigation item is selected. This listener    * will also be notified when the
> currently selected item is reselected, unless an {@link    *
> OnNavigationItemReselectedListener} has also been set.

So what I did is to add the next line to my code:

```
bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener { }
```

and that's all. The navController will load a fragment when an item is selected but not when an item is reselected in the bottom navigation.

Comment: Thanks, @Ocampo, It saved lots of my time.

Comment: Quick and easy. Thaanks!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the listener from `navController`:

```kotlin
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { 
    controller, destination, arguments -> 
        //destination.id for id fragment        
}
```

So the listener is triggered when the destination changes - not by clicking `bottom_navigation`. 
Because `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` is already used when `setupWithNavController` is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to ignore the user's click on the same selected item:

```
bottom_navigation.apply {
        setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            if (it.itemId == bottom_navigation.selectedItemId) {
                true
            } else when (it.itemId) { ... }
```

Comment: Hi! I am not using a list. When I say item I mean the item of the bottom navigation.

Comment: the problem with that approach is that this line bottom_navigation.setupWithNavController(navController) will not work then. So it seems the only solution is to remove the connection between navigation component and bottom navigation

Answer (score 0):

when you use `bottom_navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {  }` before `bottom_navigation.setupWithNavController(navController)` the OnNavigationItemSelectedListener is overrided inside `setupWithNavController` function. So use

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { 
controller, destination, arguments -> 
    //destination.id for id fragment        
}
```